# page redirect after success bootstrap validation without using php

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

Team,

I am trying to redirect after success form validation. If it is not success it has to be there in same page if it is success it has to redirect other page

I have added below line after was class validated code

```
$(location).attr('href', 'data.html');
```

it is redirecting to next page but I am not seeing any error message I am missing some valdiation.

Here is my entire code.

```js
$(function () {
'use strict'
$('#data_input').on('submit', function (event) {
    if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()

    }
    $(this).addClass('was-validated')
    $(location).attr('href', 'data.html');
    return true;

});
$("#resetbtn").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#data_input')
        .trigger("reset")
        .removeClass('was-validated')
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<form class="requires-validation" id="data_input" method="post" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col">
      <label> Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="projectName" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label>Code</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="projectCode" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col">
      <label>Number</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sprintNumber" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col"> <label>Start Date:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" id="fromdate" placeholder="Please Enter Start Date" name="fromdate" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col"> <label>End Date:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" id="todate" placeholder="Please Enter End Date" name="todate" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Total Days</label> <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left"
                            name="numberdays" id="numberdays" disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>-->
  <br />
  <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
  <button id="resetbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Clear</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

in your event submit. You use a validation if statement (checkvalidity).

```
$('#data_input').on('submit', function (event) {
**if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {**
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()

}
$(this).addClass('was-validated')
**$(location).attr('href', 'data.html');**
return true; ...
```

but whether it is valid or not you still perform the location redirect afterwards.
the redirect should be placed in a if instead you will always be redirected before any validation.

Comment: What I am doing wrong here

Comment: your location href is not placed well. you need to place it in a if statement because it seems that it trigger when the button is pushed with or without validation